# Is there a size limit on WritePrivateProfileStruct?

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I'm trying to write an INI file using the `WritePrivateProfileString` and `WritePrivateProfileStruct` functions.

I found that when the byte count is relatively low, `WritePrivateProfileStruct` and `GetPrivateProfileStruct` work fine, but with a higher byte count (62554 bytes in my case), the `Write` function seems to work but the `Get` function doesn't.

I haven't found any size limit for these functions on the MS documentation. Why is this happening?

Comment: the "what" would be why doesn't it work.

Comment: Which function fails, `GetPrivateProfileStructA` or `GetPrivateProfileStructW` ?

Comment: I was working with `GetPrivateProfileStructA`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I repro.  The largest buffer I can read back is 32766 bytes.  Larger values produce ERROR_BAD_LENGTH.  With the checksum and the terminating zero, looks to me that it uses an internal buffer that is (32766+2) * 2 = 65536 bytes long.  Makes somewhat sense, this is a legacy 16-bit API.

You *really* ought to consider using a regular file.  But a workaround is to split the buffer in two.